# Каковые общепринятые практики подсчета покрытия кода тестами в рамках gitlab-ci?

Tags: c++, gitlab, непрерывная-интеграция

Скажите, пожалуйста, какие практики существуют для организации в gitlab-ci проверки покрытия тестами?

У меня есть проект на C++, который я собираю на gitlab-ci при помощи cmake. Имеется два этапа. На первом этапе выполняется сборка с использованием lcov. На втором происходит запуск тестов с использованием артефактов, которые получены на первом этапе.

Сложность заключается в том, что артефакты приходится копировать из одного этапа в другой, и это занимает много времени.

Возможно, это всё нужно делать не так?

Comment: Разделение на этапы имеет смысл, когда есть необходимость выполнять их по отдельности.

Comment: То есть, имеет смысл объединить два указанных этапа в один?

Comment: Ну это вам должно быть виднее - нужны вам артефакты сборки без тестов или повторное выполнение тестов. Если не нужны, то конечно объединять.